# Calculating the convergence of $\sum_{n\ge3} \frac{ln(\frac{32}{13}\pi)}{3^{n-2}}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a relatively simple series that I'd like to find the convergence of:

$\sum_{n\ge3} \frac{ln(\frac{32}{13}\pi)}{3^{n-2}}$.

I'd like to say the following:

$\sum_{n\ge3} \frac{ln(\frac{32}{13}\pi)}{3^{n-2}}$ $=$ $ln(\frac{32}{13}\pi) *\sum_{n\ge3} \frac{1}{3^{n-2}}$ $=$ $ln(\frac{32}{13}\pi) *\sum_{n\ge1} \frac{1}{3^{n}}$ $=$ $ln(\frac{32}{13}\pi) *\sum_{n\ge1} (\frac{1}{3})^n$

Which is a typical Rienmann convergent series. However, I'm not sure I've treated the change of indices in the summation properly. Am I going wrong anywhere? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More simply recall that

$$\sum_{n\ge3} \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{n-2}=\sum_{n\ge1} \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^n$$

is a convergent [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) $\sum r^n$ with $|r|<1$.